# Having trouble iterating through a vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have been trying to code a program where I input data for a student class(with (const string &first_name, const string &last_name, float gpa, int id), that can display which students have a gpa above 1.00. I am having trouble iterating through a vector. Here is the function causing me trouble:

```
vector<Student> find_failing_students(vector<Student> &students) {
    vector<Student> failing_students;
    int endVar;
    vector<Student>::iterator it;
    std::vector<Student>::iterator &forwardmarch = &students.begin();

    while(forwardmarch != &students.end())
    {
        Student temp = Student(forwardmarch->first_, forwardmarch->last_, forwardmarch->gpa_, forwardmarch->id_);
        if(temp.getgpa(temp) < 1) {
                    failing_students.push_back(temp);
        forwardmarch++;
    }
```

the `std::vector<Student>::iterator &forwardmarch = &students.begin();` part is giving me the following error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::vector::iterator&' {aka '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >&'} from an rvalue of type 'std::vector::iterator*' {aka '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >*'}

the while loop `while(forwardmarch != &students.end())` also gives me the following error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'std::vector::iterator' {aka '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >'} and 'std::vector::iterator*' {aka '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >*'})

I have tried many things and also tried using a more typical for loop too, one like

```
for(std::vector<T>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
    it->doSomething();
 }
```

Im a little confused and am pretty new to C++, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please show the `Student` class and if possible make a [mcve].

Comment: `temp.getgpa(temp)` looks like really bad desgin. A getter as member function that get's the value from an object other than the current instance (`this`). There is no reason to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line makes no sense:

```
std::vector<Student>::iterator &forwardmarch = &students.begin();
```

On the left side, the ampersand tells that you are declaring an object reference (not an object). On the right side, the ampersand tells to obtain a pointer to the object, instead of the object itself. The correct use is to declare a new object and assign it directly:

```
std::vector<Student>::iterator forwardmarch = students.begin();
```

This is very fundamental stuff. The reading topic would be pointers and references in C++.

Comment: You might also want to mention the misuse of `&` in `while(forwardmarch != &students.end())`.

Comment: fwiw the actual issue to read about is iterators. Pointers and references is what causes OPs problem, but neither of them are needed here (as you nicely explain)

Comment: I just now realized I forgot to thank you for your great answer, I have since then looked more into pointers and how to use them properly.

Comment: @eduardopy Thank you for the feedback! If you deem my answer helpful, you can 'accept' it, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer